# Disabling new permissions after upgrading to the latest google service ads sdk?

Tags: android, admob

we recently updated our old Admob ads sdk to the latest one integrated with firebase.
Since then, our android app requires those new permissions:

> android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
>
> com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
>
> com.app.bundle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE

Note that we don't use any firebase service, except the ads.

Is it safe to disable these permissions from the final manifest so app will not require them upon install ?
Won't it interfere with proper serving of ads ?

Comment: These might be used to deliver new ads to your app, so they can be delivered immediately when the app is run, rather that waiting on connectivity at the time your app is run.

Comment: looks like removing them causes crashes on some devices, I would keep them for now unless someone from Google updates official document for the same - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/CXgecSxgsRE/kgkz7liJAwAJ